# NetworkInfo is not properly responding to network changes on phone running Nougat

Tags: java, android, background-process, networkinfo

Preface: This is working just fine on a phone running 6.0.1. but on my phone that is running 7.1.1, it is not, as shown below.

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
applicationId "com.gesslar.threshvote"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 25
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**NetworkUtil.java**
I have a BroadcastReceiver that I use to simply call NetworkUtil.updateNetworkStatus(context);

```
public static void updateNetworkStatus(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NO CONNECTION INFORMATION");
        return;
    }
    if (activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "WE ARE CONNECTED TO A NETWORK");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "WE ARE NOT CONNECTED TO A NETWORK");
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "NETWORK TYPE: " + activeNetwork.getTypeName());
}
```

**Starting with WiFi and Data Connected I have done the following tests**
*Turn WiFi OFF*

```
03-08 20:15:04.664 29796-29796/com.gesslar.threshvote D/NetworkUtil: NO CONNECTION INFORMATION
```

*Turn WiFi ON:*

```
03-08 20:15:26.333 29796-29796/com.gesslar.threshvote D/NetworkUtil: WE ARE CONNECTED TO A NETWORK
03-08 20:15:26.333 29796-29796/com.gesslar.threshvote D/NetworkUtil: NETWORK TYPE: MOBILE
```

*Turn data OFF:*

```
No log line written
```

*Turn data ON:*

```
No log line written
```

*Turn WiFi OFF and then turn data OFF:*

```
1) 03-08 20:17:13.029 29796-29796/com.gesslar.threshvote D/NetworkUtil: NO CONNECTION INFORMATION
2) No log line written
```

*With both off, turn WiFi ON:*

```
03-08 20:18:00.198 29796-29796/com.gesslar.threshvote D/NetworkUtil: NO CONNECTION INFORMATION
^ showed as soon as it started seeking for WiFi, but no further log line was written when WiFi became active.
```

I am absolutely bemused by the results. I saw somewhere else that I should bind it at runtime, however, my only activity is a Preferences activity. The app is not intended to have a runtime UI, rather using background IntentService and Notifications.

Comment: Hi friend i am also facing same issue if you got any solution post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html),

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
>   CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver
>   in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
>   broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with
>   Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

So what you need to do is start a `Service`, create a new instance of the Broadcast receiver `NetworkChangeReceiver` and register it to listen it to `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` by using

```
registerReceiver(new NetworkChangeReceiver(), new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"))
```

Comment: I am here from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42739403/4095334) question. You don't need `JobService` or anything specific. Just `Service` will do.