# Using JobService to replace BroadcastReceiver? Network changes and alarms

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, job-scheduling, networkinfo

It's becoming increasingly frustrating trying to get NetworkInfo working. I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685042/networkinfo-is-not-properly-responding-to-network-changes-on-phone-running-nouga), but I guess people haven't seen it. Anyway, I really need a solution based on my flow below. I **need** to know when my network changes so I can determine what *kind* of network it is and then make decisions based off that answer. I thought, OK, maybe I'll try JobService, but I am not having a lot of luck trying to puzzle out how to use it for my needs. My app is reactive and happens all behind the scenes and only shows a notification when the user needs to do something. So, I guess I'm looking for direction. How to use JobService to get the granular information I need * **and** * to use to replace BroadcastReceiver for both Network Changes and Alarms. I'll need to be able to cancel/modify alarms as IPs change while people roam around.

[image]